# Html and CSS, giving myself a bigger work space along with limiting where text can be

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote the code below and I was wondering if I could, in any way, make the white space of the `body` bigger. As of right now, I have the header color `#444` and, I thin,k about `130px` from the top and the footer is the same color and about `260px` from the bottom. In the middle, I have the little tiny white space for the `body`. Is there any way to open that up with still keeping my `header` and `footer` the size they are — just moving the footer down? Then my next problem is that my text in my `div` tags, in my `body` will spawn behind my `header` and/or `footer` when they are in the `body`. Is there a way I can limit that so that they will have to spawn between my `header` and `footer` in the white space? Thanks for your help and time!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>Joes Nose</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="zebusoft-logo">
                <img src="images/logo-3.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="body-text">
            <h1>Software Devlopment Company</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <div class="about-zebu">
            <p>About ZebuSoft</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fast-nav">
            <p>Nav</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    background: #444;
}






header  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:102px;
    background-color:#222;
    padding:20px;
}

footer {
    background: #222;
    width: 100%;
    height: 370px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.zebusoft-logo {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 400px;
}

.body-text {
    font-family: "Museo Sans",sans-serif;
    color: #300000;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center


}

.about-zebu {
    font-family: "Museo Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #606060;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: .1em;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
    margin-right: 1570px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
    margin-left: 120px;
}

.fast-nav {
    font-family: "Museo Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #606060;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: .1em;
    margin-bottom: .9em;
    margin-right:;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
    margin-left: 390px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqfzgkpL/)

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle

Comment: I can provide the css file, i haven't touched anything in the javascript file i just made it and linked it.

Comment: @JosKuzera We're going to need to see that CSS file. It's not necessary, but a jsfiddle would help so that we have a base fiddle to work off, rather than everyone creating their own versions. Also, You're going to want to put your <footer> inside your <body>

Comment: Did it sorry for the bad editing in im newer to the site ):

Comment: Still no answer what that guy posted didnt work how i wanted it to );

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqfzgkpL/1/)

Here I made the changes to your `HTML`, you need to nest footer into the body, I have also made changes to your `CSS`.

So now your footer will stick to the bottom and if there is overflow of text in the middle it will scroll.

Good luck..

**old**

I am not 100% sure what you have asked but here is the sample:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqfzgkpL/)

I have added a large paragraph and everything seems to be correct.

I have changed your `<div>` into a section and used `<p>` to add text. Tell me what is wrong with the page in the link? Thanks

**ADDED CSS**

```
.about-zebu {
    font-family: "Museo Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #606060;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: .1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
    width: 75%;
    float:left;
}

.fast-nav {
    font-family: "Museo Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #606060;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: .1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i didnt make sense i want that space  in the body like you have but i want the footer to lower itself i dont want to have it hidden under either of the footer or header. So text will never be under the header or footer.

Comment: @JosKuzera here http://jsfiddle.net/rqfzgkpL/1/ it works you need to make few changes follow it line by line

Comment: On that im still seeing txt under the footer?

Comment: that link still shows me overflow under the footer , when i implement that code into my website it breaks everything also

Comment: If you put position: fixed on your footer your body content will go behind it. So there isn't really a way to go around it as far as I know. You can solve it with some jQuery probably

Comment: one more question for you, im trying to make the footer and you see where i have about zebusoft and nav i want to move nav so its even horizontally with about zebusoft how can i do that?

Comment: @JosKuzera I have added some CSS to the answer, if you appreciate the help please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: What does that change?

Comment: what you did doesnt fix my problem

Comment: It moves the footer to align on the same line

Comment: @JosKuzera it does what you asked in last question

Comment: It doesnt do what i asked when i put it into my code, the text still get overlapped, all that does is make the text scollable between the header and footer thats not what i asked for